# Trigger/class on one object, updating from another unrelated object

Tags: apex, trigger, class, object

I am having trouble with this class, hoping you can help.  I am trying to pull a labor number from a SVMXC__Labor_Pricing__c object (field:  Labor_num__c), and push it into the SVMXC__Service_Order__c object (field:  Labor_num__c).

The two objects have 2 other objects in common, SVMXC__Service_Contract__c, and SVMXC__Activity_Product__c.

Somehow I am either not pushing good data into the Labor Pricing map, or I am not pulling it correctly.  I am hung up on how to interact with objects that are not directly related.  Any ideas?

```
public without sharing class ServiceOrderTriggersHandlerNEW {

    // update the labor part number (24500 number) on the Work Order from either:
    //   1.  the contract, or 
    //   2.  the linked Service Pricebook Entry, or 
    //   3.  the Standard Pricebook Entry from the Work Detail Line
    public static void UpdateLaborPN(List<SVMXC__Service_Order__c> triggerNew) {

    // Process only if 'Get Billing Part Nums' checkbox is checked.
    for (SVMXC__Service_Order__c wo : triggerNew) {
      if (wo.Get_Billing_Part_Nums__c != True) {
                          continue; // skip any further processing of this work order
      }
    }

          // Construct the 'Contracts to query' list        
          List<Id> contractsToQuery = new List<Id>();
          // Construct the 'Activity Product to query' list        
          List<Id> ActivityProdToQuery = new List<Id>();
          // Construct the 'Labor Pricing to query' list        
          List<Id> LaborPricingToQuery = new List<Id>();

        // gather the contract id from the work order and add to the 'contractToQuery' list
        for (SVMXC__Service_Order__c wo : triggerNew) {
            if (wo.SVMXC__Service_Contract__c != null) {
                contractsToQuery.add(wo.SVMXC__Service_Contract__c);
            }
            if (wo.BSP_Activity_Product__c != null) {
                ActivityProdToQuery.add(wo.BSP_Activity_Product__c);
            }

        }

        // query for the contracts and store in a map
        Map<Id, SVMXC__Service_Contract__c> contractsMap = new Map<Id, SVMXC__Service_Contract__c>([SELECT Id
                                                                                                            FROM SVMXC__Service_Contract__c
                                                                                                            WHERE Id IN :contractsToQuery]);

        // query for the Activity Products and store in a map
        Map<Id, SVMXC__Activity_Product__c> ActivityProdMap = new Map<Id, SVMXC__Activity_Product__c>([SELECT Id
                                                                                                            , SVMXC__Product_Line__c
                                                                                                            FROM SVMXC__Activity_Product__c
                                                                                                            WHERE Id IN :ActivityProdToQuery]);

        // query labor pricing object for labor part number, based on service contract
        Map<String, SVMXC__Labor_Pricing__c> LaborPricingMap = new Map<String, SVMXC__Labor_Pricing__c>([SELECT Id
                                                                                                            , Labor_num__c
                                                                                                            , SVMXC__Activity_Product__c
                                                                                                            FROM SVMXC__Labor_Pricing__c
                                                                                                            WHERE SVMXC__Service_Contract__c IN :contractsToQuery
                                                                                                            AND SVMXC__Activity_Product__c IN :ActivityProdToQuery]);          

        // set the value of the 24500 Billing Part Number for Labor on the Work Order based on the value from
        // either the contract (if specified) and then from the Labor Pricing (if specified)  

        for (SVMXC__Service_Order__c wo : triggerNew) {

            // get the contract data for this work order
            SVMXC__Service_Contract__c scontract = contractsMap.get(wo.SVMXC__Service_Contract__c);
            SVMXC__Activity_Product__c ap = ActivityProdMap.get(wo.BSP_Activity_Product__c);
            SVMXC__Labor_Pricing__c labor = LaborPricingMap.get(wo.Labor_num__c); // -----> Not sure how to call this variable ?????  wo.Labor_num__c does not exist on the work order, but on the Labor pricing object...how would I call it?

            // check to see if we have a contract from the map
            if (scontract != null) {
                if (labor != null) {     
                    // set the value of the Labor PN from the Contract (temporary)
                    wo.Labor_Num__c = labor.Labor_num__c;
                    }
                else {                        
                    wo.Labor_Num__c = 'TroySmith';
                    }

                    continue; // skip any further processing of this work order
                }
        }
     }     

   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you need to create a LaborPricingMap that is keyed by Labor_num__c values.

```
 // create a map for labor pricing per labor_num__c value
Map<String, SVMXC__Labor_Pricing__c> LaborPricingMap = new Map<String, SVMXC__Labor_Pricing__c>();

// query for the data and build the map using Labor_num__c as the key
for (SVMXC__Labor_Pricing__c lp : [SELECT Id
                                        , Labor_num__c
                                        , SVMXC__Activity_Product__c 
                                    FROM SVMXC__Labor_Pricing__c
                                    WHERE SVMXC__Service_Contract__c IN :contractsToQuery 
                                        AND SVMXC__Activity_Product__c IN :ActivityProdToQuery]) {

    // add the entry to the LaborPricingMap and use the Labor_num__c field as the key
    LaborPricingMap.put(lp.Labor_num__c, lp);

}
```

then later when you call this line, you will be able to get a value from the map using the `Labor_num__c` from the work order.

```
SVMXC__Labor_Pricing__c labor = LaborPricingMap.get(wo.Labor_num__c);
```

beware that there can only be one value per key, so if you `put()` into the map with a `Labor_num__c` value that was already in the map, it will be replaced with your new addition.

Comment: Thanks Mark.  I had been doing what you suggested, but I was having problems with null values, since the work order labor field is actually null before the trigger fires.      SVMXC__Labor_Pricing__c labor = LaborPricingMap.get(wo.Labor_num__c);

Comment: I see that now, after re-reading your original code again. You're likely going to need to use a value that exists on the work order since the labor number isn't yet populated. It looks like the `LaborPricingMap` could be keyed by `SVMXC__Activity_Product__c` instead and then you can do the `Map.get()` using the `Activity_Product__c` value instead of `wo.Labor_num__c`.

Comment: Thanks Mark, that helps.  We didn't have Activity Product on the Work Order originally.  I added it and thought about taking it off, but it appears I may need to keep it.  Thanks for your help!  Diving into the Paymetric stuff now....may have a question or two later.  Hope all is well!